# Custom loss in Tensorflow 2.0.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, loss-function

I want to implement a custom loss which can be calculated by using each sample. 
Calculation of the loss is a little complicated and requires me to use an external python file for this (or one can assume that we give the inputs to a function).

How can I implement this?
Is it possible to use `@tf.function` annotation and make it a graph?

This is how it is supposed to look

```py
def loss(input,output):
    loss = 0    
    for x, y in zip(input, output):
        sim = Class(x) 
        a = sim.GetA()
        b = sim.GetB()

        loss = loss + np.linalg.norm(np.dot(a,b)+y)
    return loss
```

Comment: anyone to help  ?

Comment: What is the model that should be updated based on the loss-values - is it "Class"? In that case exchange your Class for Model  and you can follow the suggestions in https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training

Comment: I want to update the weights of neural network based on the loss values

Answer (score 1):

An implementation of the same via PyTorch was possible as it supports dynamic computational graph